# siebel Open Ui export to Excel , works in IE fails in chrome and Mozilla

Tags: siebel

I am trying to use "Export" option in Open UI for eservice. Export works fine in internet explorer, but fails in chrome and mozilla.
In console I see the following error in all three browser , but IE get passes this error and export option works fine. Chrome/Mozilla fails at this step.Any idea on how to fix this or any idea how can we write our own jquery/javascript to export data to excel.Please let me know.

Error :Error -> Cannot read property 'focus' of null
this.document.getElementById('s_3_1_72_0').focus();
s_3_1_72_0 - This controls does exists (Radio Button), but this control has only name in html tag, doesnt have any ID specified.

input type="radio" checked="" name="s_3_1_72_0" value="All Rows In Current Query" aria-label="" title=""

input type="radio" name="s_3_1_72_0" value="Only Current Row" aria-label="" title=""

Thanks,
Raja

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the, as you mentioned getElementById, leads to crash, Internet Explorer is much more error tolerant and lets some mistakes happen, and the code that follows will be executed, not so in Chrome / Mozilla.

Therefore you could check if the "focus" is necassery and comment it out. Unfortunately, you don't have access to the Filesystem with Open UI so to self-implement an Excel Export a Business Service / Workflow is necessary so you could create and download an excel file.

Comment: Hi Myracle – 
Thanks for update. Do you know if we can comment out document.getElementById('s_3_1_72_0').focus().  
Cause this is created by SWE for applet "SWE Export Applet". 
If we can fix this issue, then my export to excel will work good, I don’t have to worry about writing a custom business service / Workflow for export.
Please let me know.

Comment: I think you can comment out the line because it dont work in any way. So if it blocks you, it should be removed.

Comment: Hi - But how do i comment it out, since that specific HTML is generated by SWE? Is there a way we can comment that out using "PM" or "PR"?

Comment: Well, I think the issue can be fixed in the web template file of the SWE Export Applet. But I am not sure if it is created it will be tough to change that behavior.